# How to move .zip folders created using Java.NIO FileSystem

Tags: java, file, zip, java.nio.file

I've created a .zip folder (compressed folder) using FileSystem, which is present in Java.nio package present in JDK 1.7 onwards.

```
        URI zipUri = new URI("jar:" + fileUri.getScheme(), fileUri.getPath(), null);
        FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipUri, env);
```

Now, I want to move the zipped folders from one directory to another, but I couldn't find any way to locate the zipped folders because it is a FileSystem and there is no method present to move it.

> Files.move() works only with either file or directory, but not with zipped folders created from FileSystem.

Can anyone point me to the right direction pls?

Answer (score 0):

How to move file to another directory in Java

Java.io.File does not contains any ready make move file method, but you can workaround with the following two alternatives :

File.renameTo().
Copy to new file and delete the original file.
In the below two examples, you move a file “C:\carpeta1\archivo.zip” from one directory to another directory with the same file name “C:\carpeta2\archivo2.zip“.

```
package com.softMolina.zip;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MoveZipExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

        try{

            File carpetaA =new File("C:\\carpeta1\\archivo.txt");
            File carpetaB =new File("C:\\carpeta2\\archivo.txt");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(carpetaA);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(carpetaB);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            afile.delete();

            System.out.println(".ZIP is copied successful!");

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for no boilerplate code. Also, my zipped folder is of type FileSystem which can't be converted to File, so the code which you have posted won't work.